How to setup Nexus repository for Python in VSCode
I am trying to setup Python pointing to Sonatype Nexus for package management. Wondering where to configure global setting to fetch packages like numpy in my script.
At my work I have many business scripts(.py) files that I have to run. Can VSCode directly access the dependencies??
VScode Terminal automatically connects to my pip installation and executes the code. But if the package is missing , script run says - first install the package and then run the script. To me it should be automatic to find the missing package and install it.
For exmaple  - This code will not run if numpy package is missing.
import numpy as np
np.__version__
print("np.__version:   ", np.__version__)
# NumPy functions and objects
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print("Array: ", arr)
# Example of using a NumPy
mean_value = np.mean(arr)
print("Armean_value: ", mean_value)
VSCode need to point to a package manager to fetch the numpy. The package source I suppose to use is nexus(widely used for java). I could not find any settings where i can point to Package manader.

Use a code block instead of marking each line individually as code.

VSC does not have native support for nexus package manager. Regarding automatically package installation, you can automatically install them when you are creating a new environment if you have a requirements.txt in your project. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1269
